# Can the Number class be used as an argument to accept numbers of all types as parameters?

Tags: java, types, numbers

I would like the method to accept ints, and doubles.
Can the Number class be used as an argument, so that all numbers can be accepted as parameters.
(I suspect that it could apply, but only to Integers, rather than ints.)

Comment: Obvious question: have you tried? I believe the answer is yes, but it would take fewer characters of typing to test this than to ask the question.

Comment: Yes you can. Why dont you try it out by yourself rather than asking here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, autoboxing works to convert `int` to `Number` just as well as from `int` to `Integer`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo(10);
        foo(10.5);
        foo(10.5f);
        foo(java.math.BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    
    static void foo(Number number) {
        System.out.println(number + " " + number.getClass());
    }    
}
```

Or rather, boxing itself only converts from `int` to `Integer`, but then a widening reference conversion converts from `Integer` to `Number`. From [JLS 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3):

> Invocation contexts allow an argument value in a method or constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1, §15.9, §15.12) to be assigned to a corresponding formal parameter.
>
> Strict invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
>
> Loose invocation contexts allow a more permissive set of conversions, because they are only used for a particular invocation if no applicable declaration can be found using strict invocation contexts. Loose invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion

In this case the loose invocation context is used (for the first three invocations of `foo`) as no method declaration can be found using strict invocation contexts.

Comment: Is there any significant risk or downside to using Number as a convenience parameter ? I feel it makes my life a lot easier if a method takes 3 Numbers rather than overloading it several times to cover all the possible combinations of primitives.